# JavaScript doesn't execute the code correctly on load, but it does on "resize"

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why it happens. I though it might be because the elements hadn't fully loaded, but it's not the case. And what weirder, is that when you resize it, it works. I tried everything but it still loads incorrectly.

The code of the vertical position is in line 18 of the javascript.js.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>gallery-js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- You must invoke the method when the elements have loaded -->
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <!-- Give the divs the classes that you will use as types to show/hide them (Example: app, web, animal, etc) -->
        <div class="class1">
            <!-- Picture from https://www.pexels.com/photo/photo-of-pink-and-blue-abstract-painting-2471235/ -->
            <!-- IMPORTANT: All pictures must have the same proportion (Example: 16:9, 3:2, etc)-->
            <img src="img.jpeg" alt="">
            <!-- You can put whatever you want in here (Example: <a></a>, <h3></h3>, etc) -->
        </div>
        <div class="class2">
            <img src="img.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="class1">
            <img src="img.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="class2">
            <img src="img.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="class1">
            <img src="img.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="class2">
            <img src="img.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="class1">
            <img src="img.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="class2">
            <img src="img.jpeg" alt="" onload="Gallery('container', ['all', 'class1', 'class2'], 20, 0, 2/3)">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Make the children position relative to this */
#container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Give the div that contain the images absolute position */
#container div:nth-child(n){
    top:0;
    position: absolute;
    /* Make the padding be part of the actual size of the element */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img{
    /* Avoid automatic image bottom margin */
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%
}
```

JavaScript:

```
"use strict";

function Gallery(container, classes, padding, max, height){
    let elements = document.getElementById(container).children;
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
            //Styling of the children of container
            let total_width = Math.round(document.getElementById(container).offsetWidth/500);
            if(total_width>3 && max!=0){
                total_width = max;
            }
            else if(total_width == 0){
                total_width = 1;
            }
            elements[i].style.padding = ""+padding+"px";
            elements[i].style.width = ""+100/total_width+"%";
            elements[i].style.left = ""+((i%total_width)*(100/total_width))+"%";
            elements[i].style.top = ""+(Math.floor(i/total_width)*( ( ( ( document.getElementById(container).offsetWidth - ( 40 * total_width ) ) / total_width ) * height ) + 40 ) ) + "px";
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
        for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
            //Styling of the children of container
            let total_width = Math.round(document.getElementById(container).offsetWidth/500);
            if(total_width>3 && max!=0){
                total_width = max;
            }
            else if(total_width == 0){
                total_width = 1;
            }
            elements[i].style.padding = ""+padding+"px";
            elements[i].style.width = ""+100/total_width+"%";
            elements[i].style.left = ""+((i%total_width)*(100/total_width))+"%";
            elements[i].style.top = ""+(Math.floor(i/total_width)*( ( ( ( document.getElementById(container).offsetWidth - ( 40 * total_width ) ) / total_width ) * height ) + 40 ) ) + "px";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle ?

Comment: Please provide a code here and not a link to your repository.

Comment: It doesn't work on the fiddle, dkw. https://jsfiddle.net/cupt5hw8/

Comment: Actually, I don't know what doesn't work as expected. Can you be more specific when you say "Js doesn't execute code correctly" ? Btw [i forked your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gw2veoch/2/), it's fine. the onLoad event seems to be blocked.

Comment: When it loads the positions are like these: https://ibb.co/8x9b495 . I have to resize it to move to the correct position even though the code is the same for load and resize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fiddle is different: there you have the `onload` attribute on a `div` element, but such element has no `onload` attribute, so its value is not executed at all. You can put it on the `body` element instead.

Also, when you make a jsfiddle, be aware that by default it wraps your code in a callback, so your function `Gallery` will then not be a global function. So make sure to change the jsfiddle config to "No wrap - bottom of <body>".

With those corrections, the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eh6jdfb1/) works fine, in the sense that the styling is applied to all container children.

Better still is to not use an `onload` attribute at all, but use JS code for that, like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>
    Gallery('container', ['all', 'class1', 'class2'], 20, 0, 2/3)
);
```

Or, if the images must be loaded before code gets executed:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () =>
    Gallery('container', ['all', 'class1', 'class2'], 20, 0, 2/3)
);
```

I would also put the styling code in a separate function, which you call on load and on resize. That way you avoid code repetition.

Comment: This code crashes: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', Gallery); , it says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null
    at HTMLDocument.Gallery (javascript.js:6) . And I tried using onload on the body element, but still it shows a vertical position error. The error shows when you have 1 or 2 columns.

Comment: First issue corrected -- the arguments need to be passed.

Comment: The second issue you mention (vertical position), seems unrelated to the question as it would be the same on the resize event.

Comment: I don't understand. It shows correctly on the fiddle but not in the browser... What happens is that it loads, the position of the elements is incorrect, then I resize it a pixel, and it corrects itself. Look, this is how I see the positions after adding the code of your fiddle: https://ibb.co/8x9b495

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. There must be something different in your code. Maybe some libraries that you load. I would suggest however that you debug, and see whether your function is *called* (use dev tools, console, ...etc)

Comment: The problem is that I just copy pasted your fiddle. That's all the content of the project, no libraries or anything. I think it's a JavaScript bug, or Chrome/Firefox. Are you using Safari? I already debugged and got nothing.

Comment: If it works in the fiddle, it should work when you copy it. Otherwise it means you don't have the same thing as the fiddle, since the fiddle is also run in your browser, whichever browser that is. If you can somehow link to the site where it doesn't work, I could maybe find out what the difference is.

Comment: Which version of Safari are you running? Note that you need Safari 10+ to use much of the EcmaScript 2015 syntax.

Comment: I use Chrome and Firefox, and I have the bug on both of them :/. I asked if you used Safari because I though that you might be using it since it didn't work for me on Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: Strange, I don't see any problem on that site with Chrome, Firefox, or Edge. No errors in console, and the images are responsive on load.

Comment: Have you checked with the selector if the position of the items is correct on load? Because at first sight they seem correct. And are you checking the gallery with 2 columns? Because in 3 or more the bug doesn't appear.

Comment: What do you mean with "selector"? With 2 columns it looks fine to me. Also, resizing with 1 pixel does not change anything more than just what 1 pixel adjustment needs. I'm sorry, but I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: With selector I mean the mouse that lets you hover over elements and show with colors the margin/padding of them. When I load, the distance is wrong. Pf...... What can I do, if it doesn't work for me it might not work for other people, I can't release this even though the code is right, ffs. Should I report the bug?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, so before you think of reporting a bug, make sure you can *very clearly* demonstrate the unexpected behaviour to others. At least I don't see anything wrong with it (except for the thing I pointed out in my answer).

Comment: Well I have cleaned the browsers twice, deleted all extensiones, restarted the pc, and it still shows the problem. This is the first time that something like this happens to me. I'll try from my other pc, but something is wrong in this one for sure, and I don't know what it is. Thanks for all your support though :)